# logical plan and physical plan for pig operators

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

When studying the `Pig Latin`, I am sort of confusing about the idea of `logical to physical plan for operator like Co_group`, which is shown as following. I do not quite understand how to understand this graph.

[image]

Comment: Explained well in this post  https://haritbigdata.wordpress.com/2015/08/05/hadoop-pig-logical-plan-vs-physical-plan/

Answer (score 1):

For depth understanding of Logical plan and physical plan, refer this link :

http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch07.html#explain